# Angular 15 HMR not working, Throwing Circular Dependency error

Tags: angular, angular15, hot-module-replacement, hmr

**Error** Unhandled Promise rejection: NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected for ApplicationRef.

**hmr.ts**

```
import { NgModuleRef, ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';

import { createNewHosts } from '@angularclass/hmr';

export const hmrBootstrap = (
  module: any,
  bootstrap: () => Promise<NgModuleRef<any>>
) => {
  let ngModule: NgModuleRef<any>;
  module.hot.accept();
  bootstrap().then(mod => (ngModule = mod));
  module.hot.dispose(() => {
    const appRef: ApplicationRef = ngModule.injector.get(ApplicationRef);
    const elements = appRef.components.map(c => c.location.nativeElement);
    const makeVisible = createNewHosts(elements);
    ngModule.destroy();
    makeVisible();
  });
};
```

**main.ts**

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { hmrBootstrap } from './hmr';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

const bootstrap = () => platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);

if (environment.hmr) {
  if (module['hot']) {
    hmrBootstrap(module, bootstrap);
  } else {
    console.error('HMR is not enabled for webpack-dev-server!');
    console.log('Are you using the --hmr flag for ng serve?');
  }
} else {
  bootstrap().catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

I've implemented HMR in standard way which all documents states. But somehow after upgrading angular 13 to angular 15 it started throwing circular dependency error.

[image]